# Make item for RecyclerView set at a certain level but still able to scroll up on different phones

Tags: android, android-view, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically adjust the starting position of the first item in a `RecyclerView` at a certain location like this:

[image]

[image]

So the item starts near the bottom of the screen, but is still able to move all the way up.

How can I achieve this?

I was thinking to initially "pre-scroll" an item to a certain position above the bottom view bar, maybe get the height of the bottom view and adjust the pre scroll dynamically for different screen resolutions?

Currently I am using a custom ViewHolder that is just an empty view which is the header to achieve this, but it doesn't scale properly on different phones.

Comment: when u finish scrolling and go up again do you still need to be in the adjusted starting position

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MounirElfassi yes when I scroll back up again it should be back at the adjust position

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting a padding on top with `android:paddingTop="400dp"` and then set `android:clipToPadding="false"`

Comment: Yes but how to scale properly for different phones?

Comment: Instead of using the fixed value of 400dp you can set a dimension in the dimensions.xml resource file and adjust for different configurations. Reference it with @dimen/...

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically instead with Display, DisplayMetrics, or WindowManager?

Comment: I don't know anything about these two but you can use the dynamic dimension value programmatically with `int spacingInPixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.grid_spacing)`